# Suggested iOS workflow for an enterprise licensed app larger than 2Gb

Tags: ios, ipad, bundle

I know the max app size for the app store is 2Gb, but it is my understanding that with enterprise license you can have larger apps. In this case I need to store 500,000+ images on the ipad which sum up to 8Gb. This will be the only app installed on a 64Gb iPad3. The images must be stored on the iPad, on runtime only 36 images of 768 x 768px will be loaded at a time.

Anyone have some insight on how to handle a task like this and even if it is possible?

So far I am trying to make a bundle with 1gb to test but this is making the build process and debug painfully slow

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to first ask yourself if an ipad can handle 36 images of 768x768 in memory.<br>
Take a look at that: when you load an image (better say when an image needs to be drawn on screen) the image is decompress in memory thus 4(num of colors)*768*768 equal about 2.4MBytes * 36 about 84MBytes in memory. The ipad will not event lunch a memory warning. Try to find a solution for that first that makes you load less images per times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after being downvoted for whatever reason I'll answer my own question with the results of several proof of concepts made. Downloading images from a server was not an option due to business requirements.

I've successfully got an enterprise app running on iPad with 4gb of test data and 144 1024 x 1024 images in runtime. The catch is that the images are loaded sequentially and flattened into a canvas to reduce memory consumption. It seems the iPad terminates your app if memory consumption spikes, if you increase memory consumption gradually it will allow you to go up more depending on current open apps and processes.

Answer (score 2):

Create the app with just a few images and have a button which lets the users download the rest of the images from a server which your app saves.